# Terminal with real time dmesg output

Tags: linux

Somewhere in the past, I saw a linux box with real time dmesg terminal - i.e. you push Ctrl-Alt-F12 and a terminal with with fresh dmesg output pops out.

How can I reproduce such effect?

I know about the trick with *watch* command, but that's not the solution I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to need to edit your **/etc/syslog.conf**.

Adding a line like:

```
kern.*          /dev/tty10
```

Would output all kernel info to that tty.  You'll need to figure out which tty is assigned to contol-alt-f12.  There are many more examples in **man syslog.conf**.

Comment: Note that, on some Ubuntu, the base install has rsyslog in place of syslog, so that the config file is /etc/rsyslog.conf, with default configuration in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf (same syntax)

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 I also had to add syslog to the tty group, otherwise syslog doesn't have permission to write to a console -> `sudo usermod -aG tty syslog
`

Answer (score 2):

You need configure this in /etc/syslog.conf (or /etc/syslog-ng.conf depending on syslog version) directing kernel messages to /dev/vc/12 (for alt-ctrl-12).

If there is a log file already, a manual solution is to do something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/kernel.log > /dev/vc/12
```

But the permanent way is to set it up for your flavor of syslog

(in my archlinux install there is a predefined rule for this in /etc/syslog-ng.conf, uncommenting it would turn exactly this feature on)

Answer (score 1):

Is this not what `xconsole` does in X11?
Otherwise you `tail -f /dev/console`. If I'm wrong here, and `dmesg` shows more than the console, then you need to look into `syslogd`.
Set your `/etc/syslog.conf` to either send kern messages to console, or to whichever stty is attached to the alt-ctrl-F12, which should be `/dev/vc/12`.
**So that's `/etc/syslog.conf`**:

```
kern.*  /dev/vc/12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run

```
cat /proc/kmsg
```

for realtime dmesg output in current terminal

Comment: What does this do? One or two line answers are generally not a good format at SU.

Comment: I tried `tail -f /proc/kmsg` and then inserted a USB flash drive, but nothing was output, despite dmesg showing output

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can configure your Linux to execute a Shell Script when you press some keys. For example for Gnome: http://www.codejacked.com/create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux/

The shell script file will contain the dmesg command.

Comment: The point is, it wasn't a shortcut-induced dmesg invocation. It was a virtual terminal designated to the specific task of displaying kernel output, you couldn't modify it content in any way.

Comment: OK, something similar to this:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=798247 but instead a desktop background application something to launch with a keyboard shortcut