# How do I make dmesg post output to tty12 in real time?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Terminal with real time dmesg output](https://superuser.com/questions/30123/terminal-with-real-time-dmesg-output)

I want to use tty12 for system messages. Is there a way to mirror all kernel messages to there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to tell `syslog` to do it.  [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslog-ng) article on the Arch Wiki shows a configuration which logs messages to `/dev/tty12` (see `destination d_console`).